# Math Equation To Solve Tournament Winnings

Tags: php, math, equation

Here is what I'm looking for. To buy into a tournament a user must pay a buy in, say $10. If the user wins the first round match they advance to the 2nd round. They then can buy out of the tournament ($20), or play again. If they win they would then have $40. They can follow this pattern for a certain number of rounds. They can buy out or keep playing.

I can't for the life of me figure out the equation to use in php to get the players current winnings based on buy in and their current round. Please help!

I thought it would be as simple as buy in * round, but clearly it's a little more detailed then that.

round 1 - $10
round 2 - $20
round 3 - $40
round 4 - $80

Comment: Looks like `$10*2^(roundNum-1)` to me.

Comment: I don't know why, but the question sounds familiar...

Comment: How is this related to php or programming?

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko maybe due to the $ signs ...

Comment: @ChaosCakeCoder: that's right, we do it for the $$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $10 be BaseAmount

The forumula is BaseAmount * (2 power roundno-1)

round 1 = $10 * (2 power 0) = $10 * 1 = $10

round 2 = $10 * (2 power 1) = $10 * 2 = $20

round 3 = $10 * (2 power 2) = $10 * 4 = $40